# Store value from wx.button event

Tags: wxpython

having this:

```
def imp(self, event):
    file = 'nofile'
    wildcard="CSV (*.csv)|*.csv"
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(
        self, "Select File", os.getcwd(),"",wildcard,wx.FD_OPEN)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        file = dlg.GetPath()
    dlg.Destroy()
    return file
```

how can I store `file` when the event is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

In your classe's `__init__` method, add a line like this:

```
self.file = None
```

Now just change your `imp` method to use `self.file` instead of `file`. You should be able to just change it to the following:

```
def imp(self, event):
    wildcard="CSV (*.csv)|*.csv"
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(
        self, "Select File", os.getcwd(),"",wildcard,wx.FD_OPEN)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.file = dlg.GetPath()
    dlg.Destroy()
```

Now when you press `OK` in your application, the `self.file` property will be updated and you can access it throughout your class.